# How to install a bcachefs supporting kernel on Linux Mint 21.x and LMDE6?

Tags: linux-mint, kernel, bcachefs

**2023-10-31, Bcachefs Merged Into The Linux 6.7 Kernel:**

- https://www.phoronix.com/news/Bcachefs-Merged-Linux-6.7
- https://web.archive.org/web/20231103095158/https://www.phoronix.com/news/Bcachefs-Merged-Linux-6.7

**Remark:**

It's known it's easyly possible to update the LM21 used Kernel 5.x to the  "Kernel 6.1.0-1004-0em" the following way, but this kernel dosnt support bcachefs.

**See the follow sample:**

```
uname -r
# Kernel 5.x...
```

Install the new Kernel version:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-oem-22.04c
```

Reboot

Check the new Kernel version:

```
uname -r
Kernel 6.1.0-1004-0em
```

It is also known that with the follow GUI based Ubuntu Mainline Kernel Installer software, it should be possible to replace an obsolete kernel supported by LM 21. However, this GUI software does not seem to allow the selection of either of the two bcachefs-supporting kernels mentioned above:

- https://github.com/bkw777/mainline
- https://web.archive.org/web/20230209075725/https://github.com/bkw777/mainline

**Some links:**

- https://web.archive.org/web/20230205130327/https://bcachefs.org/bcachefs-principles-of-operation.pdf
- https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/impish/man8/bcachefs.8.html

Answer (score 0):

Add bcachefs Ubuntu kernel PPA bcachefs to your system:

"They get built for the latest Ubuntu development release, and are a regular Ubuntu kernel with all the Ubuntu sauce (zfs, nvidia modules, virtualbox, etc) rebased onto bcachefs master.

Adding the PPA with sudo add-apt-repository ppa:raof/bcachefs and then installing the linux-bcachefs package will get you the most recent kernel, and keep updating that kernel as I upload new versions. You also probably want bcachefs-tools from there, too."

**Source:** https://web.archive.org/web/20230421084110/https://www.reddit.com/r/bcachefs/comments/h797z8/ubuntu_bcachefs_ppa/

Or build your own kernel:

Thats what the bcachefs Howto tell about:

"**Build the bcachefs-kernel branch.**

Firt run the following command to download a kernel branch with the bcachefs patches.

```
git clone https://evilpiepirate.org/git/bcachefs.git
```

This is slighly more complicated to explain. It's best you look up a tutorial for your specific distribution.

During the configuration make sure you enable `CONFIG_BCACHEFS_FS`. To check run `grep CONFIG_BCACHEFS_FS .config` in in the kernel source.

Tip if your distro kernel supports it you can extract the .config used by your distribution, by running `cat /proc/config.gz | gunzip > /tmp/distro.config.`

**Source:** https://web.archive.org/web/20230421125110/https://bcachefs.org/Howto/

Comment: THX. Did you test it ?

Answer (score -1):

What the gento howto tell about:

"Installation

While the bcachefs developers are working towards mainlining the filesystem, as of November 2022 the easiest way to try bcachefs is to check out the bcachefs sources and build a new kernel.

```
user $git clone https://evilpiepirate.org/git/bcachefs.git
user $cd bcachefs
user $cat /proc/config.gz | gunzip > .config
```

An alternative to this is to get a copy of a bcachefs patch from a patchset such as linux-tkg and apply it to the system kernel as a user patch.
Kernel configuration

Activate the following kernel options:

```
KERNEL bcachefs filesystem support (BCACHEFS_FS)
```

File Systems --->
<*> bcachefs filesystem support

Note
If the crc32c-intel module is available and bcachefs loads before it (or is built in) the CRC32 hardware instruction will not be used resulting in increased system resource utilisation. Ensure that the module loads before bcachefs or build it into the kernel to avoid this.
Additional software

**Install sys-fs/bcachefs-tools:**
`root #emerge --ask sys-fs/bcachefs-tools`"

**Source:** https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Bcachefs

**Feel free to improve the answer.**

Comment: THX. Did you test it ?

Answer (score -1):

Linux Mint 21 should be a Ubuntu derivate, so the chache should exist, its possible to build a bcachefs supporting kernel by follow toturial:

its describe the follow steps:

- Add Sources
- Install Dependencies
- Get Bcachefs Source Code
- Build BcacheFS
- Get your kernel config:
- Configure the kernel
- Build the kernel
- Install
- Creating a BcacheFS Volume
- Mounting a BcacheFS Volume
- Adding the mount command to cron

For more details, see:

- https://web.archive.org/web/20230212224001/https://www.rwardrup.com/bcachefs-on-ubuntu-20-04/

Feel free to improve.

Comment: I see no reason for three separate answers. You should be able to summarise them in a single answer.

Comment: @Alfred.37, That seems to me to be the most promising answer so far. THX !!! Can you possibly fill it with more details please?

Comment: Pls replace "bbcachefs" by "bcachefs".

Comment: "bbcachefs" replaced by "bcachefs" Done. THX